# How to update/insert data from joined tables using data adapter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables student, subjects and test which I have inner join them using stored procedure to bind in datagridview like this

```
Student F.N | S.NAME | L.NAME | HISTORY | GEOGRAPHY | MATH
```

Now the problem is I want to update the marks of the subjects directly using data adapter but these are joined tables and which a pivot (subject and test).

How can I solve this problem cause for me it's confusing?

Comment: Add sample data & desired result.

Comment: look at the code of the stored proc, it will show how the tables are actually structured. your updates/inserts need to suit that structure.